# npm is failing to parse package.json

Tags: javascript, json, npm, truffle

I'm new to using npm and node I created a react app with truffle unbox react which uses npm init react-app. I have tried reinstalling npm and clearing the cache but I keep getting the following error when I run sudo npm start.

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /home/a/Documents/so/client/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token { in JSON at position 634 while parsing near '...rsion"
npm ERR! JSON.parse     ]
npm ERR! JSON.parse   }
npm ERR! JSON.parse }
npm ERR! JSON.parse 
npm ERR! JSON.parse {
npm ERR! JSON.parse "name": "mapboxAnd...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/a/.npm/_logs/2020-06-21T17_39_45_819Z-debug.log
```

My package.json looks like this.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "web3": "1.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell package.json is nothing but json. Please help me understand this error. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json is a valid JSON file, the error is somewhere else.
Can you please do the below:

1. run the package without sudo, e.g. "npm start" instead of "sudo npm start", you shouldn't run your packages as root.
2. have a look at the log file "/home/a/.npm/_logs/2020-06-21T17_39_45_819Z-debug.log" and post more details.